# How to update every document in collection based off another collection with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with a single document that contains many stats of different people.
It is structured like so:

```
// Stats list:
[{
   id: .... ,
   lastUpdated: ... ,
   stats: {
      Person1: {stat1: 0, stat2: 0, stat3: 0},
      Person2: {stat1: 0, stat2: 0, stat3: 0},
      ...
      Person100: {stat1: 0, stat2: 0, stat3: 0}
   }

}]
```

These stats are updated every 24 hours.

Now I have a few hundred listings that contain a specific list of the people in the first collection.

```
// Listings:
[{
   id: ...,
   persons: {
       Person1: {stat1: 0, stat2: 0, stat3: 0},
       Person43: {stat1: 0, stat2: 0, stat3: 0}
   }
}]
```

I want to be able to update all person stats in these listings compared to the persons in the stats section in the first collection I showed.

My logic is something along the lines of this:

```
await Listing.updateMany({}, { $set: { persons: { "some kind of query" } } });
```

But I am not sure how to most efficiently go about this.

Comment: Maybe you want to rethink your schema, using objects as maps in mongo is often not the best choice and is difficult to manage, you could use something like: `persons:  [{ key: 'person1', stat1: 0 }]`

Comment: @Tizio Fittizio Is it better practice to use an actual map instead? I am using react redux to manage the state of these people and it’s easier to use a map to find a person than to loop through an array of objects.

Comment: I said that is not a best practice in mongodb, if you are modeling your schema to have thing easier in js then no wonder its harder to manipulate data with mongo query/aggregation language then, no one forbid to use say a [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) to have appropriate objects in your db (mongodb) and your language (js) tough