# Updating async forEach to update every document property based off property from another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this piece of code that works. However, I am not sure why and I feel like it might behave inconsistently.

```
  await Listing.find({}, (err, listings) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    listings.forEach(async (listing) => {
      //console.log(listing);
      let championsUpdate = {};
      for (let key in listing["champions"]) {
        championsUpdate[key] = rankingDB[key];
      }

      await Listing.updateOne(
        { _id: listing._id },
        { $set: { champions: championsUpdate } }
      );
    });
  });
```

Pretty much I am finding all the listings that I need to update, and then for each listing I am updating one of the properties based off the data I retrieved earlier.

So far it's been behaving appropriately but I remember being told to avoid using async await in a forEach loop because it does not behave as we expect. But I can't figure out why this is working and if I should avoid the forEach and use a forOf. I am also worried about having nested async awaits.

Does anyone know if something like this is ok? For more context on my [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822273/how-to-update-every-document-in-collection-based-off-another-collection-with-mon?noredirect=1#comment111160632_62822273)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the callback in the forEach loop is async, things that follow the call to forEach may execute before forEach finishes, and it will not wait for each iteration to finish before continuing.
For example the await in front of the `updateOne` call is actually pointless, since the outer async function isn't awaited on, which shows that it is probably not behaving the way you intend it to.

The reason it is recommended that you not use `async` inside a `forEach` is that it is almost never behaving the way you intend it to, or you don't actually need it, or you may forget that you called it that way later and unintentionally cause a race condition later (ie: it makes the execution order hard to reason about and virtually unpredictable).  It has valid use if you actually do not care about the results of the call, when they are called, and when they resolve.

Below is a demo showing how it can cause unexpected results.  `sleep` with random time to make each `.updateOne` call resolve at random times.  Notice that call to `` console.log(`Will execute before...`) `` executes before the forEach iterations.

```js
async function runit() {
  await Listing.find({}, (err, listings) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    listings.forEach(async (listing) => {
      //console.log(listing);
      let championsUpdate = {};
      for (let key in listing["champions"]) {
        championsUpdate[key] = rankingDB[key];
      }

      await Listing.updateOne(
        { _id: listing._id },
        { $set: { champions: championsUpdate } }
      );
    });
  });
  
  console.log(`Will execute before the updateOne calls in forEach resolve`)
}
runit()
```

```html
<script>
// mock data with sequential _id from 0...9
listings = Array(10).fill().map((_,_id)=>({_id, champions: {1:1,2:2}}))
rankingDB = Array(10).fill({1:1.1,2:2.2})

// Promise that resolves in ms milliseconds
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// mock Listing
Listing = {
  find(x, fn) {
    console.log('find')
    return new Promise(res=>
      res(fn(undefined,listings)))
  },
  // updateOne resolves after random time < 1000 ms
  async updateOne({_id}) {
    await sleep(Math.random()*1000)
    console.log('updateOne with listing _id=',_id)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: So would it be ok to leave it as is since I do not have anything that follows the forEach call? Or would it be safer to use another way of iterating asynchronously?

Comment: If you don't have to worry about the updateOne operations finishing (and don't have to check for errors, although error checking doesn't necessarily need to be waited on either) before continuing, such that for example you have code later that read or update those values and would enter a race condition if the updates happened concurrently, then it should be fine, yes.  You might want to batch the updates, but if there are no performance issues it is probably fine.  Since it appears you are saying the updates are the last action, and it looks like mongodb updates with unique ids, it looks safe

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now, I appreciate the help!